# Problems with shifter?

Tags: gears, shifting

I have problem with my gears. How can I fix this or where I can find wire like this?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3):

You have a Shimano Positron shifter and derailleur. If you didn't know you own a bit of bicycle gear shifting history. See Sheldon Browns [Shimano page](http://www.sheldonbrown.com/shimano.html) and look for 'Positron'.

Simply googling for 'shimano positron cable' should produce some hits. There appear to be some cables for sale on Ebay.

You should probably try to find out more about the Positron system, especially if there are different variants that might require different cables. I think there were at least a couple of models.

Update 1: I did some google image searching and I believe you have a Positron II Six Speed.

Update 1.1: Further research reveals it's a Positron *FH* Six Speed. Positron II was 5 speed.

Update 2: Looking at how the cable is attached to the shaft, I think it is soldered. You may be able to re-solder the cable using a small butane torch. Or even use high strength epoxy to glue it back.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a full answer, but I've been asked to post it anyway. In my opinion the picture seems to show the lever of a Shimano Positron system, which predates the modern systems with Bowden cables out of braided steel cables (confusingly called "wires") and a spring to return. The Positron system uses either two steel cables (each pulls the rear derailleur in one direction) or one solid steel wire (not braided) that can both push and pull.

I think you have the latter. If you do, somewhere on the lever or on the rear derailleur it should say "Positron" and you should have one continuous cable housing from the lever to the derailleur.

They are still available, but harder to find and more expensive than modern-style shift inner cables. Look for a "Shimano Positron wire". It will have a thicker rod on one end with a sort of barrel-like ending, just like the thing sticking up in your second picture. It should look like this and come with a special end cap for the other end.
[image: Shimano Positron wire]

Comment: FYI this is a perfectly appropriate answer. Even if you don't have complete information it's good to post what you do have if it helps the OP. +1